# How to change channel permissions in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want the bot to toggle just send messages permissions when the command is invoked.
code:

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    async def lock(self,ctx):
        await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

this works , it changes the send messages permissions to false for default role but it also effects the other permissions, it sets them to neutral(default). I don't want that, I want it to just toggle send messages and leave everything as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [<TextChannel>.overwrites_for()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.overwrites_for) to get the current permissions on the role and then set `send_message` to False from the permissions it has.

```py
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    async def lock(self,ctx):
        perms = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
        perms.send_messages=False
        await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=perms)
```